# FirebaseError: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'grpc'

Tags: angular, firebase, grpc, angular-universal

I'm trying to create an Angular4 application with Server Side Rendering (SSR) using Angular Universal and Firebase Cloud Functions.

The application runs with no problem using `ng serve`, but after building the app and server using `ng build --prod --aot -app 0` and `ng build --prod --aot -app 1`, and compiled server file with `tsc -p ./server/tsconfig.functions.json` and start the app with `firebase serve --only hosting,functions`, I get an an error in the console: `Error from emulator. FirebaseError: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'grpc'`.

[image]

I have tried to re-install firebase-functions inside the functions directory, but that didn't solved the issue either.

Here is my dependencies object:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "firebase": "^4.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
  },
```

I've spent several hours trying to figure out this issue, but with no luck.
Is there anyone who's experiencing this error? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realise you have probably either fixed this by now or have moved on, but for anyone else like myself who came with similar problems, this is how I solved it. (NB I didn't have exactly the same problem as you, but it also couldn't find `gprc`).

I installed a Node module called [reinstall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reinstall):

```
npm install reinstall -g
```

Then navigated to the `functions` directory, and just ran:

```
sudo reinstall
```

Waited for it to finish and then `sudo firebase functions:shell` worked fine after that!

NB I think this may update your dependencies depending on how your `package.json` is set up, but all the dependencies in mine used the [caret range](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) which only allows some minor and patch updates.